# jQuery - Remove border from preceding sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove the border-bottom on the sibling above the element that is hovered over on the menu. I do not know if I am using the wrong function or if it is some other issue. Thanks for any feedback.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav_1487666 li a').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).prev().css("border-bottom", "none");
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav_1487666">
    <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Landscaping</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Irrigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Porous Pave</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo Dumpsters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Lawn Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().prev()` assuming the border is on the li. if you want it on the anchor then `$(this).parent().prev().find('a')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$(this).prev().css("border-bottom", "none");
```

To

```
$(this).parent().prev().css("border-bottom", "none");// To remove border from li
```

or

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('a').css("border-bottom", "none");// To remove border from a
```

Comment: I don't think `$(this).parent().find('a').prev()` works http://jsfiddle.net/jZkW7/1/ should be `$(this).parent().prev().find('a')` .parent() gets the current li, .prev() gets the prev li and find gets the anchor

Comment: The third option worked for me as the border was on the anchor element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the border is on the li, something like this -

```
#nav_1487666 li{
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 5px;
}
```

then change your jquery selector to

```
$('#nav_1487666 li').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).prev().css("border-bottom", "none");
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZkW7/)